# What's wrong with the following assignment in Java Generics

Tags: java, generics

I am just starting with Java Generics and the following code does not make any sense to me.

```
List<? extends Number> lint = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// following throws error
List<Number> lint2 = lint;
```

### [Extra Details]

I know that `List<Interger> != List<Number>` but what's the use of '?' operator then? I created an arraylist of integers which I passed to some List which can accept lists containing doubles,floats or integers. Why can't I assign this to List. Can all of this be attributed to **Strict type safety**?

I am using this as a reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html

Comment: your lint list says it can only accept subclass of Number. Number is not subclass of number hence it doesn't work.

Comment: @almasshaikh You are wrong.
`List<? extends Number> lint = new ArrayList<Number>();` correctly working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is simple : `lint` is an `ArraysList<Integer>` that is `lint.add(10)` is right, `lint.add(2.5)` is wrong.

But if Java compiler accepted `List<Number> lint2 = lint;`, `lint2.add(2.5)` should be acceptable because `2.5` is a `Number` and would allow to put a `Double` in a list of `Integer`.

Hope it is more clear now ...

Answer (score 6):

easy,

> `List<Integer>` is not a subtype of `List<Number>` even though `Integer` is
>   a subtype of `Number`.

for any subclass of `Number`(`? extends Number`) as `Integer`.

[image]

see more [Generics, Inheritance, and Subtypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html)

Comment: I have read this and I agree with you but what's the use of '?'(upperbound) then,if I can't assign Integer list to Number list?

Answer (score 1):

/**The abstract class Number is the superclass of classes BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, Float, Integer, Long, and Short. */

/**Subclasses of Number must provide methods to convert the represented numeric value to byte, double, float, int, long, and short.

So you have to Type cast */

```
    List<? extends Number> lint = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    List<Number> lint2 =  (List<Number>) lint;
    lint2.add(123);
    lint2.add(1234);
    System.out.println(lint2);
```

Comment: Your solution worked but I think I didn't get it yet.

Comment: Dear n00b,  do you known concept of abstract class,superclass and subclasses? here syntax List<? extends Number> abstract class Number is the superclass of classes BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, Float, Integer, Long, and Short. when we List<Number> assign  subclass of Number must provide methods to convert the represented numeric value to byte, double, float, int, long, and short. So we need type cast 'lint' to List<Number> type

Answer (score 0):

lint is of type ArrayList()
and lint2 is type of List()
Here you can say that ArrayList is subclass of List so

```
List l1 = new ArrayList();
```

and like that Integer is subclass of Number ,so

```
Number i = new Integer(5);
```

But `List<Number> != List<Integer>`
That's why it is giving error.
They are different.

Answer (score 0):

In lint2 one can add any child of Number.
In lint no such thing; as one does not know the specific ?.

```
    lint.add(new Integer(3000)); // Error too
```

Hence read "? extends T" as a specific (unknown) type. Only for reading a Number, not writing.

Answer (score 0):

`List<Number>` and `List<? extends Number>`. Hence you cannot directly assign `lint` to `lint2`, You should cast it to `List<Number>` type.